# Output of an Addition of Attributes of multiple instances of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

salesMy basic setup:
I have a User Model that has a has_many/belongs_to relationship with a Workday Model.
The Workday Model has attributes called 'sales' and a 'date'.

What I want to do, is to add up the sales attribute of different workday instances during a given timespan.
I started with trying to first of all add up ALL sales from that user which resulted in a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sales' for nil:NilClass
```

The code looks like this:

```
def all_sales
  s = 0.to_f
  c = @user.workdays.count
  for i in (0..c)
    s += @user.workdays[i].sales
  end
end
```

Whats the most elegant way to go about this?

Edit 1:
Typo, it was *user.workdays[i].sales*, not *.count*. Sorry about that.

Comment: How are you calling it? There's a `nil` workday. Also, `s = @user.workdays.inject { |acc, w| acc + w.count }` and I don't get the `s = 0.to_f`, why not just `s = 0.0`? Be wary of using floats if you're doing any meaningful calculations involving money.

Comment: Or even `def all_sales; @user.workdays.sum(&:count); end` (untested; close).

Comment: Isn't 0.0 and 0.to_f the same? And 0.0 is more or less a short notation? Anyways, the calculation is not really important, its just a very basic overview of the profits.

Comment: @Quantaqa It's the same, but calling a function to create a float 0.0 from an int 0 is bizarre. `0.0` isn't a "short notation" for `0.to_f`, it's a number. Why call a function on a number when you can just write a number?

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought it would be a shorthand for the call, thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done through Arel

```
@user.workdays.sum(:sales)
```

Also you could query specific time interval

```
@user.workdays.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?",start_date, end_date).sum(:sales)
```